# Read/Write data in file or SQlite for Android?

Tags: android, file-io, android-room

The main dilemma I am stuck into is whether I should use Room database or Files to save my data.
Please skip the security, encryption/decryption part for now.
The thing is I need to store complex object like of a usual transaction like below

`Transaction(id, entryTime, exitTime, pricingScheme, amount, vehicleNumber, etc etc.)`

So I am having a device with just 1 gb of RAM and when data increases by like 1000 entries then the query takes a lot of time to get the searched data and sometimes device hangs.

I know the Room Lib is highly optimised but lets also consider the below scenario for sometime.

So I got this suggestion from someone to store the data in text files after certain limit lets say after 700 entries store the data in file.

I will write data line by line as mentioned below.

`749463(some ID) Transaction1 (Json)`

`804830(some ID) Transaction2 (Json)`

But the main issue arises here is how I can query the data from a text file?
Is there any was other than reading the file line by line and comparing the ids to get the desired entry?

This doesn't sound very practical right, I reacted the same so just need your reviews/directions on this before I start my POC project.

Or is there any other way of handling the above situation?

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is POS? What is POC? `store the data in text files after certain limit lets say after 700 entries store the data in file.` What is an entry? Do you mean: after 700 transactions?

Comment: And why would you put all info of a transaction in a database or file? Cant you start telling why as that tells us maybe what you can do best.

Comment: All a Room is, is a file, so trying to use a text file won't help you. I think what you are suggesting is to have 2 or multiple instances of the data storage? If the query you need has to go over all of the data it will be much much slower so you are better off with having just one and waiting it out.

Comment: POC is Proof of concept like a demo project or prototype

Comment: @blackapps I need all the data related to a transaction in db because i need to get the data and show it in the ui ?